# Simplemechine forum Rss link

Tags: rss, forum, smf

I am using simplemechine forum script(SMF) old version(1.1.6).
I want to rss to my facebook page.when 
I search in google,the rss type for my forum is 
http://example.com/**index.php?action=.xml;type=rss**.
This rss link is only work in old version IE.This rss link is not work with firefox,chome,lastest broswer and facebook page.
Plsase help me how I can get rss link for my forum.
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should consider upgrading your forum because of security risks.
What you need is to auto post your forum topics to your facebook page/profile?
If is that what you need you can use a 3rd party website that provide this kind of service.
The one i use and recoment is http://twitterfeed.com/, where you can automaticly post all your forum updates to twitter AND facebook.
About your RSS URL, the default feed of SMF forum is really /index.php?action=.xml;type=rss wich will display ALL updates of your forum, including new topics, and new answers to topics. You can freely manage this feed type to show only new topics, or only topics from one determined category, etc. Good Luck.